# Incorrect Syntax Near Keyword 'OPTION' in CTE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I get a "Incorrect syntax near keyword 'OPTION'" error when attempting to save a view in SQL Server 2008.  I'm trying to add a MAXRECURSION option to the end of my common table expression.  All the examples I've seen and working CTEs I've created before don't mind the "OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)" at the end of the CTE.

Anyone see why I'm getting this error?  The CTE works without the OPTION clause, although it reaches the maximum number of recursions (100).

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT
    CDay,
    InvAcct,
    BuyerCode,
    PartNumber,
    ROP,
    ROP_ROQ,
    DailyDemand,
    StartingInvQty,
    SchedDeliveryQty,
    CAST(StartingInvQty - DailyDemand/2.0 AS decimal(18,4)) AS ProjInvQty
  FROM
    qryInventorySimulation
  WHERE
    MBC = 'B' AND
    CDay = CAST(CAST(GETDATE()AS date) as datetime)

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    qryInventorySimulation.CDay,
    qryInventorySimulation.InvAcct,
    qryInventorySimulation.BuyerCode,
    qryInventorySimulation.PartNumber,
    qryInventorySimulation.ROP,
    qryInventorySimulation.ROP_ROQ,
    qryInventorySimulation.DailyDemand,
    qryInventorySimulation.StartingInvQty,
    qryInventorySimulation.SchedDeliveryQty,
    CAST(CTE.ProjInvQty + qryInventorySimulation.SchedDeliveryQty - qryInventorySimulation.DailyDemand AS decimal(18,4)) AS ProjInvQty
  FROM
    qryInventorySimulation INNER JOIN CTE ON qryInventorySimulation.InvAcct = CTE.InvAcct AND qryInventorySimulation.PartNumber = CTE.PartNumber AND qryInventorySimulation.CDay = DATEADD(d,1,CTE.CDay)
  WHERE
    qryInventorySimulation.CDay <= DATEADD(d,120,GETDATE())
)

SELECT * FROM CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't apply this option within the view. You would need to apply it to the query calling the view. e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.V
AS
    WITH CTE AS
    (   SELECT 1 AS A 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT A + 1
        FROM    CTE
        WHERE   A < 50
    )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    CTE;
GO
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.V
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

If you think of a view more as a stored subquery than a stored query (yes it can be called on it's own but it is not necessarily), and remember that its definition is expanded out into the main query (unless you are using `NOEXPAND` - which you could not on a view that contained a recursive CTE anyway), so in essence you are trying to do something like this:

```
WITH RecursiveCTE AS (...)
SELECT *
FROM T
    INNER JOIN 
    (   SELECT  *
        FROM    RecursiveCTE
        OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
    ) c
        ON c.SomeField = T.SomeField;
```

Whereas the correct syntax would be:

```
WITH RecursiveCTE AS (...)
SELECT *
FROM T
    INNER JOIN 
    (   SELECT  *
        FROM    RecursiveCTE
    ) c
        ON c.SomeField = T.SomeField;
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful explanation and example but I'm still having trouble applying it to my situation.

I took my CTE and saved it as a separate view (let's call it "V" as in your example).  I then created another view as follows:

    'SELECT * FROM V OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);'

But still same problem when I go to save the new view: "Incorrect syntax near keyword OPTION".  I thought this followed your example.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I also noticed that MAXRECURSION option is accepted if I add it to the end of the CTE definition within a stored procedure.  It won't be accepted within a view.  Although it gets accepted within a stored procedure, it still doesn't have any affect on the maximum number of recursions.  Weird.

Comment: "*I then created another view as follows: `SELECT * FROM V OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);`  But still same problem"* - Is this surprising? It doesn't matter how many times you nest your view you cannot apply query hints to it. In itself it is not a full query, therefore cannot have hints.

Comment: "*Although it gets accepted within a stored procedure, it still doesn't have any affect on the maximum number of recursions. Weird.*" - It definitely does have an effect - [see this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91b54/1)

Comment: @GarethD See whether I understand this correctly. A view is a subquery, since `SELECT * FROM theview;` means `SELECT * FROM (SELECT …);`. So what you can do in a view is limited to what you can do in a subquery, which excludes hints and the `ORDER BY` clause (except for the workaround). I suppose the same would apply to table valued functions which answers another question of mine. That was helpful.

Comment: @GarethD Is that meant to be `NOEXPAND`?

Comment: Yes, it should have been `NOEXPAND`