# Table Valued Function with Recursive CTE

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, common-table-expression

Just for fun, I’m trying to write a table valued function to generate a table of dates. For testing purposes, I am hard-coding values which should be passed in variables.

By itself, this works:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT cast('2021-10-01' AS date) AS date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(day,1,date) FROM cte WHERE date<current_timestamp
)
SELECT * FROM cte OPTION(maxrecursion 0);
```

Note the `OPTION` at the end.

As a function, it won’t work unless I remove the `OPTION` clause at the end:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dates(@start date, @rows INT) RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT cast('2021-10-01' AS date) AS date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(day,1,date) FROM cte WHERE date<current_timestamp
)
SELECT * FROM cte   --  OPTION(maxrecursion 0)
;
```

For the test data, that’s OK, but it will certainly fail if I give it date at the beginning of the year, since it involves more than 100 recursions.

Is there a correct syntax for this, or is it another Microsoft Quirk which needs a workaround?

Comment: I'd normally use a calendar table for this. Or a tally table starting with a base date and dateadding from there as with your CTE.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks, but the question is really about the recursion; it’s not necessarily about the dates.

Comment: Default maximum recursion is 100. You can specify more by adding the option clause, specifying 0 for up to 32767 (or specify 32767). That's just how it is.

Comment: @TT. yes, but I can’t add that to the function.

Comment: Indeed, you can only use the option clause in the statement that is using the function, not in the function definition itself.

Comment: @TT. That seems to work. It’s awkward, though, to require the caller to add that. A function should really more self-contained. Is there no other solution?

Comment: Avoid recursive CTEs, specifically for what you are doing. Use a calendar table, or a number table (tally table) to calculate consecutive days.

Comment: @Manngo _Is there no other solution_ Of course there is - don't use recursion. Use a tally table. Simple searching will find many example of generating them (and the very common calendar table which is just a simple application of a tally table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a multi-statement Table Valued Function:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dates;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dates(@start date, @end date) RETURNS @dates TABLE(date date) AS
BEGIN
    WITH cte AS (
        SELECT @start AS date
        UNION ALL
        SELECT dateadd(day,1,date) FROM cte WHERE date<@end
    )
    INSERT INTO @dates(date)
    SELECT date FROM cte OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
    RETURN;
END;
GO
SELECT * FROM dates('2020-01-01','2021-01-01');
```

Inline Table Valued Functions are literally inlined, and clauses such as `OPTION` can only appear at the very end of an SQL statement, which is not necessarily at the end of the inline function.

On the other hand, a Multi Statement Table Valued function is truly self-contained, so the `OPTION` clause is OK there.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this may be the answer.

In an answer to another question, @GarethD states:

> If you think of a view more as a stored subquery than a stored query … and remember that its definition is expanded out into the main query …

([Incorrect Syntax Near Keyword 'OPTION' in CTE Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188350/incorrect-syntax-near-keyword-option-in-cte-statement?rq=1#answer-24188586)).

If that’s the case, a view can’t include anything that can’t be included in a subquery. That includes the `ORDER BY` clause and hints such as `OPTION`.

I have yet to make sure, but I can guess that the same goes for a Table Valued Function. If so, the answer is no, there is no way include the `OPTION` clause.

Note that other DBMSs are more accommodating in what can be included in subqueries, so I don’t imagine that they have the same limitations.